# Why do people say "Ich gehe auf die Toilette" instead of "Ich gehe in die Toilette"?

Tags: usage, preposition

The title says it all. I understand that in this case the acusative case should be used, but why "auf" instead of "in"? Can I say "Ich gehe in die Toilette"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because *Toilette* means in everyday language toilet and not bathroom, so *in die Toilette gehen* means to step into the toilet bowl.
*Auf die Toilette gehen* comes from *auf die Toilette setzen* (to sit on the soilet seat)

The room, in which the toilet is, is called *Toilette* in German ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilette)), too. However, I ([and the internet agrees](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/ich-gehe-in-die-toilette-richtig-wenn-man-die-toilette-als-raum-definiert)) would use  *Toilette* as name for the room only in the sense of "Wo ist die Toilette? (Where is the bathroom)" or "Ich gehe zur Toilette". But in both cases it could also be understand as the toilet itself, too.

If the room contains a toilet and a shower, I would use *Bad* or *Badezimmer* instead.
For example:

> A: *Wo bist du?*
>
> B: *Ich bin im Badezimmer* (even though I am actually sitting on the toilet) or *Ich bin auf der Toilette* or *Ich bin auf dem Klo.*

Comment: According to dict.leo.org, "Toilette" can also mean "bathroom". In Spanish, this would be "baño", which refers to the room where the WC is, not precisely the WC.

Comment: @Charlie I do not know how it is said in Spanish but I think English and German are similar at this topic. For example, in English, you say also I go to the toilet, not I go into the toilet.

Comment: @Charlie, you are right, I edited my question.

Comment: "into" might probably imply you're trying to enter the bowl - both in English and German

Comment: @Iris Without any context to the sentence in the question, how do you know that, as you say, "Toilette here means toilet not bathroom"? Maybe the test continues in this way: "Ich gehe in die Toilette und schraube die Kloschüssel ab."

Comment: @what, I should cancel the "here". "Toilette" is the toilet and not the room in Germany (even though officially the room is called the same). I would say "Ich gehe ins Badezimmer und schraube die Kloschüssel ab". And the internet agrees ;) http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/ich-gehe-in-die-toilette-richtig-wenn-man-die-toilette-als-raum-definiert

Comment: @Iris Schau hier: http://www.123-architektur.de/upload/projecten/23/0.jpg Da ist links eine Toilette und rechts ein Badezimmer. In dieser Wohnung kannst du im Bad keine Kloschüssel abschrauben.

Comment: @iris I agree with your answer but I wouldn't refer to _gutefrage.net_. To my experience there is a very good reason why that site is not called _guteantwort.net_. ;-)

Comment: @Charlie The problem comparing German (or English) with Spanish is that while the first have "in/auf/an" ("in/on/at"), in Spanish they're just "en". This answer is correct: Toilette may refer to both the furniture and the room where it's placed, but it would *never* be understood as "room" when you say where you are...

Comment: @dave_alcarin That's not entirely true, because in Spanish there're other prepositions that mean the same as "in/on/at". We have 2 different words to express two different concepts which are: the WC or the device where we sit on and the physical space where this device is located or installed. In Spanish you say "voy al baño" (ich gehe aufs klo), which means you are heading to the room where the WC is located and not necessarily you are going to use the WC or sit on it. "Estoy en el baño" (ich bin im Klo) means that you are physically inside the room, but not necessarily sat on the WC. Cheers.

Comment: @Charlie I know how Spanish works (to a relatively wide extent), being native speaker myself ;) But taking your example of "voy al baño", you are using "a", which in this case is a preposition expressing direction ("to" in English - I'm going to the bathroom, mostly "zu" in German, in this case "auf" - Ich gehe aufs Klo). My point with "en" vs. "in/on/at" is as follows: Think of *en* in "estoy *en* el baño" (ich bin *auf* die Toilette) vs. "estoy *en* el salón" (ich bin *im* Wohnzimmer), vs. "estoy *en* mi sitio" (ich bin *an* meinem Platz).

Answer (score 5):

"In die Toilette" can be interpreted as *into* the toilet bowl instead of the bathroom (although people are smart enough to figure out that that is not what you mean).

Here are a few example of "in die Toilette":

- "Nicht mehr benötigte Medikamente gehören nicht in die Toilette oder den Ausguss." ([Umweltbundesamt](https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/en/publikationen/arzneimittel-nicht-in-die-toilette-spuele))
- "Mir ist das Handy in die Toilette gefallen (...)" ([Reinigungsforum.de](http://reinigungsforum.de/threads/handy-in-die-toilette-gefallen-was-kann-ich-tun.408/))
- "Darf man Speiseabfälle in die Toilette schütten?" ([Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/2013/52/speiseabfaelle-toilette))

Many people use "ins Klo" as a synoym for "in die Toilette", and "aufs Klo (gehen)" as a synonym for "auf die Toilette (gehen)".

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. No one would think I put my vacuum cleaner in the toilet bowl if I say: "Ich stelle den Staubsauger in die Toilette."

Comment: @what, do you really say this? I wouldn't.... For me that is a "Bad/Badezimmer"

Comment: @Iris Ich weiß nicht, was deine Muttersprache ist, aber ein Raum mit nur einer Toilettenschüssel und einem Waschbecken ist im Deutschen kein Badezimmer. In einem Badezimmer wasche ich mich. Das mache nicht nicht in der Toilette. So haben z.B. die Züge der Deutschen Bahn eine Toilette, aber kein Badezimmer. Versuch mal den Schaffner zu fragen, wo das Badezimmer ist. Ich muss schon lachen, wenn ich das schreibe! In manchen deutschen Wohnungen gibt es eine Kloschüssel im Bad, aber sehr häufig sind Bad und Toilette getrennt, und in Einfamilienhäusern gibt es oft eine sogenannte Gästetoilette.

Comment: @what Do you mean that the sentence "Nicht mehr benötigte Medikamente gehören nicht in die Toilette oder den Ausguss." is wrong??

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Is that your first sentence? No. I wrote: "Your first sentence is wrong." Your first sentence is a generalization, and it is wrong. I said nothing about the rest of your answer, so don't bring it into the discussion.

Comment: @what There is no need to become argumentative. I have edited it now.

Comment: @what, meine Muttersprache ist deutsch. Und ja, ich würde in der Bahn auch das 'Klo' oder die 'Toilette' suchen. Allerdings würde ich trotzdem den Staubsauger neben dem Klo oder 'im kleinen Bad' (so hieß das bei mir zuhause) suchen. (So, und nun warte ab, wie die Masse hier entscheiden)

Comment: Ah. Okay. Das hab ich nun noch nie gehört. Du kannst ja aber trotzdem nicht einfach ignorieren, dass der Duden unter Toilette auch den Raum aufführt und beispielsweise auch Wikipedia meint: "Daneben wird der Raum, in dem sich eine solche Vorrichtung befindet, ebenfalls Toilette genannt." Es ist ganz offenbar nicht nur, wie du schreibst, eine "offizielle Bezeichnung" (denn die ist "WC"), sondern verbreiteter Sprachgebrauch.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is what you want to express.

If you want to say that someone is going to defecate, you are speaking of the toilet bowl ("Toilette") and you do not go into the bowl to defecate but sit on it. The common way to express this is to say: "Ich gehe auf die Toilette." or: "Ich gehe zur Toilette."

If you want to say that someone enters the room ("Toilette") that contains the toilet bowl for some other reason than defecation, you may say both: "Ich gehe auf die Toilette." (and maybe mislead the listener to think that you need to pee) and "Ich gehe in die Toilette." (which will make it clear that you do not intend to use the toilet bowl).

To be more explicit, "in die Toilette gehen" is not false. According to the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Toilette), you can say "auf die, in die, zur Toilette gehen".

There are [many examples](http://www.dwds.de/r?q=in%20die%20Toilette&corpus=zeit&date-start=1946&date-end=2015&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50) for "in der Toilette sein" in the corpus of *Die Zeit*, for example: "Vor Gericht sagte er, er habe in der Toilette einen Einbrecher vermutet." Here, the room is meant, and "in" is used. Had the author written "auf", the readers would have assumed the burglar was sitting on the toilet bowl.

[Other corpora](http://www.dwds.de/r?q=in%20die%20Toilette&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50) also list countless examples for "in die Toilette gehen", for example: "Nach ein paar Abenden fiel allerdings auf, daß ich in die Toilette hineinging, aber nicht wieder herauskam."

So don't let the other, wrong answers dissuade you from using a perfectly correct German phrase and feel free to say "Ich gehe in die Toilette" whenever you just want to do your hair.